# Using company-mode completion with read-from-minibuffer

Tags: completion, keymap, company-mode, minibuffer

The following code (mostly coming from [here](http://sixty-north.com/blog/writing-the-simplest-emacs-company-mode-backend)) creates a company-mode back-end and binds `TAB` to it:

```
(require 'company)

(defconst sample-completions
  '("procedural" "functional" "high-level" "low-level" "statically-scoped" "dynamically-scoped"))

(defun company-sample-backend (command &optional arg &rest ignored)
  (interactive (list 'interactive))
  (let ((my-completions (copy-sequence sample-completions)))
    (case command
      (interactive (company-begin-backend 'company-sample-backend))
      (prefix (and (eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)
           (company-grab-symbol)))
      (candidates
       (remove-if-not
        (lambda (c) (string-prefix-p arg c))
        my-completions)))))

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-sample-backend)

(define-key company-mode-map (kbd "TAB") 'company-sample-backend)
```

I have checked that the above works. That is, when I put a regular buffer (such as `*scratch*`) in `company` mode, I can invoke completion by pressing `TAB` and the `sample-completions` collection is used for completion.

Now I am trying to read a string from mini-buffer with auto-completion. To make sure that the mini-buffer is in `company` mode, I evaluate:

```
(defun my-minibuffer-mode ()
  (company-mode 1))
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'my-minibuffer-mode)
```

Now I try:

```
(read-from-minibuffer "Prompt: ")
```

However, what I get is completion from the English dictionary and not from my `sample-completions` collection. How do I fix this?

Comment: You seems to limit the `major-mode` in `company-sample-backend`. How about rewriting like `(prefix (company-grab-symbol))`?

Comment: Or try this major-mode check instead: `(memq major-mode '(fundamental-mode minibuffer-inactive-mode))`. The result seems to work as expected.

Comment: Or indeed drop this comparison if this backend is only going to be used in the minibuffer.

Comment: @Dmitry To tell you the truth, I do not really understand what this code is doing. I took it verbatim. I think you are talking about the check `(eq major-mode 'fundamental-mode)`. Is an active mini-buffer in a special mini-buffer mode that is different from the fundamental mode?

Comment: @Dmitry You are right. Changing this check for `t` makes it work!